# How are groups created in maxout units when dividing the set of inputs  into groups of  values?

Tags: neural-networks, feedforward-neural-networks, hidden-layers, relu

I don't get $G^(i)$the set of indices into the inputs for group $i$, $\{(i −1)k+ 1, . . . , ik\}$ when creating a maxout units/function, these thing that outputs the maximum element of groups: $$g(z)_i= max_{[j∈G^{(i)}]}z_j$$

> Maxout units(Goodfellow et al., 2013a) generalize rectiﬁed linear
> units. Instead of applying an element-wise function $g(z)$,
> maxout units divide $z$ into groups of $k$ values. Each maxout unit
> then outputs the maximum element of one of these groups:
>
> $$g(z)_i= max_{[j∈G^{(i)}]}z_j$$
>
> where $G^{(i)}$is the set of indices into the inputs for group
> $i$,$\{(i −1)k+ 1, . . . , ik\}$.
>
> This provides a way of learning a piecewise linear function that
> responds to multiple directions in the input $x$ space. A maxout unit
> can learn a piecewise linear, convex function with up to $k$ pieces.
> Maxout units can thus be seen as learning the activation function
> itself rather than just the relationship between units. With large
> enough $k$, a maxout unit can learn to approximate any convex function
> with arbitrary ﬁdelity. In particular, a maxout layer with two pieces
> can learn to implement the same function of the input $x$ as a
> traditional layer using the rectiﬁed linear activation function, the
> absolute value rectiﬁcation function, or the leaky or parametric ReLU,
> or it can learn to implement a totally diﬀerent function altogether.
> The maxout layer will, of course, be parametrized diﬀerently from any
> of these other layer types, so the learning dynamics will be diﬀerent
> even in the cases where maxout learns to implement the same function
> of $x$ as one of the other layer types.
>
> [Deep Learning, Bengio and al. page 190](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html)

I tried to work it out with a concrete example:

Let's take a concrete example with k = 3. In this case, the groups would be as follows:

$$G^{(1)} = {(1 - 1)3 + 1, ..., 1 * 3} = \{1, 2, 3\}$$
$$G^{(2)} = {(2 - 1)3 + 1, ..., 2 * 3} = \{4, 5, 6\}$$
$$G^{(3)} = {(3 - 1)3 + 1, ..., 3 * 3} = \{7, 8, 9\}$$
And so on...

So, in this example, if we have 9 inputs, we'd have 3 maxout units, and each maxout unit would use 3 inputs to calculate its output, choosing the maximum from these 3 values.

Suppose we want to model the cost of producing a certain number of units of military weapons as a function of the quantity produced. We can use a piecewise linear function for this.

So let's imagine that the production cost is defined by a convex function with three pieces (k = 3):

- For the first 100 units produced, the cost is \$10,000 per unit.
- For 101 to 200 units, the cost is \$8,000 per unit.
- For 201 units and above, the cost is \$7,000 per unit.

So here, I guess each maxout unit would take as input the quantity produced, and each group $G^(i)$ would be associated with one of the pieces of the function.

For example, if we wanted to calculate the cost of production for 150 units, I'm not sure but I guess we'd have :

$G^{(1)} = \{1, 2, 3\}$ corresponding to the first part of the function (\$10,000 per unit).
$G^{(2)} = \{4, 5, 6\}$ corresponding to the second part of the function (\$8,000 per unit).

**I don't get what are $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and $\{4, 5, 6\}$ standing for, concretely**

If I apply the maxout function for each group, I guess it means that maxout unit 1 will select the maximum of the values associated with $G^{(1)}$, and maxout unit 2 will select the maximum of the values associated with $G^{(2)}$, and so on ... but then it doesn't make any sens

Indeed, for 150 units, I guess maxout 1 would give a value of \$10,000 per unit, and maxout 2 would give a value of \$10,000 per unit, ... I don't know how I am expected to calculate the total cost of production then ...

I am a slow but passionate learner in math and deep learning. Don't hesitate to explain it to me as if I was a teenager.